# Why are Content Porter 2013 exports failing with 'Error while getting virtual URL mappings table'?

Tags: 2013, content-porter-2013

After upgrading our system to SDL Tridion 2013 and Content Porter 2013, content exports are failing immediately with the following error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A01C9): This key is already associated with an element of this collection|Error while getting virtual URL mappings table[Export failed at ExporterBL.ExporterClass.Export(String& Summary) at Tridion.Conte

Has anyone seen this error before and does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This is an extremely long shot, but I had this just today again, but then for a Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2 system, with Content Porter 2009 SP2:

Ensure that in your Tridion_CM database, in the *TRUSTEES* table, the **Everyone** group has ID 1 **and** that any other row in the *TRUSTEES* table does not have its *NAME* column value set to "Everyone". It sometimes happens that during an upgrade the Everyone group gets the wrong ID.

Disclaimer 1: I am sure that this is true in the versions described above. It may not be the case for a 2013 system. But especially the "This key is already associated with an element of this collection" error had me stuck for a few hours as well, as logically you'd think that export -or import zip files were off, which is not the case at all.

Disclaimer 2: I don't know whether doing direct manipulation is supported (I suppose not), but I do have the queries here if you want them. I'll post them if you want when you can check the DB.